# how can I know an Apple Pay receipt is valid?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, applepay

Recently I encountered a problem. Someone is selling our app's service (in-app purchase) in the Internet, which is a bit cheaper than our price.

I have checked the receipt received from client through the api of Apple server (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt):

```
{
  "receipt": {
    "app_item_id": "123456",
    "bid": "com.aaa.bbb",
    "bvrs": "2.11.11",
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
    "is_trial_period": "false",
    "item_id": "123456",
    "original_purchase_date": "2018-05-14 02:13:01 Etc/GMT",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1526263981276",
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-05-13 19:13:01 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_transaction_id": "90000426694387",
    "product_id": "char1200",
    "purchase_date": "2018-05-14 02:13:01 Etc/GMT",
    "purchase_date_ms": "1526263981276",
    "purchase_date_pst": "2018-05-13 19:13:01 America/Los_Angeles",
    "quantity": "1",
    "transaction_id": "123456726694387",
    "unique_identifier": "abcdeffb70076be1430c754569fd1fba2f1546bc",
    "unique_vendor_identifier": "ABCDEF-ABCD-4D86-824B-840CFF57D6FF",
    "version_external_identifier": "123476292"
  },
  "status": 0
}
```

I can't find anything wrong. I have listed the questions below:

1. Could someone tell me how can I check the validation of the purchase directly?
2. If the money is not payed into my account, how can I check this situation?
3. Why can others buy our service in a lower price?

Comment: Someone else cannot sell your products, especially cheaper. the product is linked to your account and app. Use the unique vendor identifier, bundle id and product id to verify whether its a valid purchase or not.

Comment: @Scriptable As you can see, when I check the receipt, everything is valid. But absolutely it's a not a normal thing. I'm sure I can't receive the money, but I can't find the reason.